# Execute method every second

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to execude some code every second in android, but I'd like to do is in one thread (main thread). So far I have this:

```
locationTimer = new Timer("locationTimer", false);
locationTimer.schedule(new LocationCheckerTask(this), 0, 1000);

public class LocationCheckerTask extends TimerTask {
    private GeoWatcher watcher;

    public LocationCheckerTask(Context context) {
        watcher = new GeoWatcher(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // funky stuff
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `Timer` class runs it's tasks on another thread.
Why I want to do this in a single thread?
Code in `run()` method will be executing really fast, so I figured I don't need another thread for it. What I want to do is to construct separate threads in `run()` method based on condition calculated every second. So instead of having child thread constructing another threads, I'd like to do this on the main one.

Comment: are you using this code in Activity?

Comment: yes, `locationTimer` initialization is done in `Activity`

Comment: The fact that the run method will execute fast is not a reason to not run it in a separate thread. If you want to run it on the main thread you will need a way to wait for a second which will block your main thread....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

```
public class Job implements Runnable{
    private Handler handler;

    public Job () {
       handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
       loop();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // funky stuff
        loop();
    }

    private void loop() {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this code block my main thread for one second (not desired behavior)?

Comment: @MarekMałek No. The main thread will only be blocked during the execution of `run()`. So any heavy lifting in `run()` should be done in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

use `runOnUiThread(Runnable)` method of Activity to run the task in UI Thread

```
public class LocationCheckerTask extends TimerTask {
    private GeoWatcher watcher;

    public LocationCheckerTask(Context context) {
        watcher = new GeoWatcher(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // funky stuff
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the Handler is a perfect candidate for such tasks (dont try to combine TimerTask + runOnUiThread - it is useless as it uses a Handler under the hood)

Answer (score 0):

```
private Runnable fiveSecondRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (count5 < 0) {
            switchT030Sec();
        } else {
            tvSec5.setText(""+count5);
            Log.v("5sec set", "yes");
            count5--;
            man.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }

    }
};
```

and start it by calling

```
man.post(fiveSecondRunnable);
```